# Bash trigger wget command and don't wait for response, continue to the next command

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Is there a way I can trigger a `wget` command via bash script and continue to the next command in the bash script without waiting for a response from the `wget`? i am executing a command which should take lots of time and don't want wget to hold for a response nor re-trigger it after timeout has been timeout limit

Comment: what about running it in the background? `wget ... &`?

Comment: its the last command in my bash script [because it takes a lot of time] and i dont want wget to re-trigger it when it reaches its timeout. plus im thinking about placing other commands after it...

Comment: Was that a response to @fedorqui's suggestion? Because if it was I don't see how it applies (nor do I think I fully understand it).

Comment: @EtanReisner i ment that im not sure using `wget ... & -othercommand` will do since its already the last command im performing (wget) plus i might add more than 1 command after wget, that means i need to do `wget ... & command & command` ?

Comment: `&` doesn't join commands, that is `&&`. Running `wget ... & -othercommand` will give an error.

Comment: Huh? The `&` sends *just* that command into the background so the script does not wait (continues to the next line). If the script ends at that point that is fine. If it doesn't that is fine also (other commands will run). You do not need `&` on any other commands because you used it on the one command.

Comment: @Broshi a single `&` at the end of command in bash runs the preceding command in the background.  A double `&&` works as an `and` to string commands together as you're doing in your comment

Comment: You can try a sample example script: `echo 1; sleep 30 &; echo done;` When you run it, you will get `1` and then `done`. If in the meanwhile you `ps -ef | grep sleep` you will see `sleep` is still running even after the script kind of finished.

Comment: I see, I was confusing it with `&&`, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `--background` option, as it goes to background and saves the output to a log

```
--background
       Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log
```

Example:

```
$ wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/wily-server-ppc64el.iso --background
Continuing in background, pid 79783.
Output will be written to ‘wget-log’.

$ cat wget-log 
--2015-05-12 11:21:35--  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/wily-server-ppc64el.iso
Resolving cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.164, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1f
Connecting to cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.164|:80... connected.
....
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that option.